# Is there any example of distributed TensorFlow training by using multi-node multi-GPU?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

By searching on Google, I can find the following two types of deployment about tensorflow training:

- Training on a single node and multiple GPUs, such as [CNN](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/deep_cnn);
- Distributed training on multiple nodes, such as [between-graph replica training](https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed#replicated_training);

Is there any example of using multi-node multi-GPU? To be specific, there exist two levels of parallelism:

1. On the first level, the parameter servers and workers are distributed among different nodes;
2. On the second level, each worker on a single machine will use multiple GPUs for training;

Answer (score 1):

Tensorflow Inception model documentation on GitHub ([link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/inception#how-to-train-from-scratch)) has a very good explanation on different types of training, make sure to check it out and their source code.

also, you can have a look at this [code](http://deepspeech.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/DeepSpeech.html), it also does distribute training in a slightly different way.